# Issues getting REMOTE_USER passed from Shibboleth when using IIS

Tags: tomcat, iis, shibboleth

I'm using Shibboleth as a SP to pass authenticated users to a tomcat application via IIS.

Testing this application shows that I am receiving many elements from the IdP in the header, but sadly not the REMOTE_USER (the one I need). This is despite the value being configured in the ApplicationDefaults section of the shibboleth2.xml file.

I understand that it's simple enough to do this using apache, but I need to go the IIS route here. Looking at other posts around this, we've already tried setting the attributePrefix="AJP_" (for our tomcat application), but this didn't resolve the issue.

Has anyone encountered anything similar..?

Answer (score 0):

IIS does not allow modules to set REMOTE_USER. It should be populated in `HTTP_REMOTE_USER`.

[1] https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeAccess#NativeSPAttributeAccess-HTTP_REMOTE_USER

Comment: Note that page now says "This was a mistake, and has already led to (now patched) security problems. While not formally deprecated, you should consider use of this feature highly discouraged, and should not develop new applications based on this header name."